# custom post type for custom talbe

Tags: custom-post-types, database

Where would I start if I want to have a custom post created each time data was submitted from a form on the front page for non-logged in users? I have the script set up to send the data to a custom table, and to retrieve the data. 
I would like to put a function into a conditional that would create a post of the data that is submitted.
again, the constraints would be a form on the front page or any user-facing page for non-logged in users.

Comment: Did you have a look at `wp_insert_post()`. Link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you're asking how do you create a post from a form thats submitted by a user?

These tutorials might help: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/ or http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-to-your-wordpress-site-a-quotes-plugin/

It shows how to create post from a forms input.

For the conditional part, if you want them to be logged in use this:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
  return '<p>You need to be logged in to do whatever this is....</p>'; 
}
```